# Avoid multiple event listeners from .focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have a textbox that I am invoking a keyboard stroke on focus:

```
$myTextBox.on('focus', function(e){
    $(document).keydown(function(e){ 
       if(e.which==13)
         e.preventDefault() 
    });
    $(document).keyup(function(e){
       if(e.which ==13)
         alert("hey");
    });
});
```

If I click on this multiple times pressing 'enter' once will cause many alerts, how can I avoid this so that only it is only invoked once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding the event listener every time the field gets focus.

Just add the keydown, keyup listener on the document ready function...

```
$(function() {
    $("#myTextBox").keydown(function(e){ 
       if(e.which==13)
         e.preventDefault() 
    });
    $("#myTextBox").keyup(function(e){
       if(e.which ==13)
         alert("hey");
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ShHkP/

Answer (score 0):

Like others have said, you don't have to keep adding the event on `focus`.  As well, you should just attach the event to the textbox itself because that is in fact what you're trying to do when you add the event on focus.

```
$myTextBox.on({
  'keydown': keyDown,
  'keyup': keyUp
});​
```

So that your application doesn't go into an enter-alert-ok loop, you have to turn off the keyup listener before the `alert()` call, and then turn it back on after hitting ok.

[Here's a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/scrimothy/3S4LJ/1/)

Answer (score -1):

```
var alreadyPressed = false;
    $("textarea").keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alreadyPressed = true
        }
    });
    $("textarea").keyup(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13 && !alreadyPressed) {
            alert("hey");
            alreadyPressed = false;
        }
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/Dr6t2/

Comment: You add the keyup/keydown listeners to the entire document?

Comment: And why is there a downvote? I hate people just downvote on answers and do not provide a reason for that.

Comment: Adding the keyup/keydown event to the entire document is overhead and not needed for what he is trying to do.

Comment: @Calvin.Allen - What is the difference... -_-

Comment: You're adding the event listeners to the document every single time that textbox gets focus.  Bad.  Not only that, but adding the listener to the DOCUMENT, means it will fire FOR THE DOCUMENT, not just the textbox.

Comment: @Calvin.Allen - It is fixed now.

Answer (score -1):

I see what you're trying to do (or not?). You could just attach the event to the form and exclude the textarea instead of adding it to the document everytime the input gets focused.

```
$('form').on('keydown', function( e ) {
  // Prevent submit when pressing enter but exclude textareas
  if ( e.which == 13 && e.target.nodeName != 'TEXTAREA' ) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Comment: He doesn't even mention textarea, just textbox.